# CUDA SystemInformation

Tags: cudalink

I run the following:

```
 ClearAll;

 Needs["CUDALink`"]

 CUDAQ[]
```

The last returning True.

I then run SystemInformation[].  Before I get the expected panel with the various tabs ("Kernel", "Front End", "Links", "Parallel", "Devices", "Network", "Machine"), I get the following error:

Join::incpt: Incompatible elements in Join[<|intt->RowBox[{[Integral],RowBox[{[SelectionPlaceholder],RowBox[{[DifferentialD],[Placeholder]}]}]}],dintt->RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox[[Integral],[SelectionPlaceholder],[Placeholder]],RowBox[{[Placeholder],RowBox[{[DifferentialD],[Placeholder]}]}]}],rintt->RowBox[{UnderscriptBox[[Integral],RowBox[{[SelectionPlaceholder],[Element],[Placeholder]}]],[Placeholder]}],sumt->RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox[[Sum],RowBox[{[SelectionPlaceholder],=,[Placeholder]}],[Placeholder]],[Placeholder]}],prodt->RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox[[Product],RowBox[{[SelectionPlaceholder],=,[Placeholder]}],[Placeholder]],[Placeholder]}],<<38>>,cI->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorI],cK->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorK],cS->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorS],cW->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorW],cY->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorY]|>,{<<1>>},{<<1>>}] cannot be joined.

Anyone have any idea why this occurs and how to make it disappear?

I'm running Ver. 12.3 on a Windows 11 64-bit platform using the CUDADriverVersion 496.49 with A GeForce GTX 1080 with Max-Q Design.  I get the sense that CUDALink on my machine is not quite set up correctly.  I can execute some CUDA commands without error but not all.  I'm trying to reach a point of stability with various examples available in WR documents and videos, so I can get to the point of actually learning how to create CUDA programs using CUDALink.

Comment: Have you installed the CUDA Toolkit as detailed in the [CUDALink Setup tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html)?  Also, are you running the latest driver for your NVIDIA card? Also, check the compute capability of your card.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this error can be made to disappear by first invoking the following command.

```
Needs["CUDADriverLink"]
```

At least on my machine.

Comment: Your code above (without `` ` ``) returns an error ("Invalid context specified at position 1 in Needs["CUDADriverLink"]"). If I use ``Needs["CUDADriverLink`"]``, I get a "Cannot open ``CUDADriverLink` ``". Which one did you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant to type  Needs["CUDADriverLink`"]  Without it (and ignoring my typo above) SystemInformation[] gives me a Join error.  Thanks for catching the typo.